# Custom TableViewController in Storyboard is not accessible?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a Storyboard with a UINavigationController and one TableViewController so far.
The TableViewController is a custom class of UITableViewController, I set this on the storyboard.
In my Appdelegate in didFinishLaunching I have the following code:

```
NSLog(@"rootviewconroller: %@",self.window.rootViewController);

//CTCAEMainTableViewController *mainViewController = (CTCAEMainTableViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
CTCAEMainTableViewController *mainTableViewController =  (CTCAEMainTableViewController *) mainNavigationController.topViewController;
NSLog(@"table: %@",mainTableViewController);
NSLog(@"table: %@",mainTableViewController.testMethod);
```

CTCAEMainTableViewController is my custom UITableViewController.

```
@interface CTCAEMainTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

But all I get back is a normal UITableViewController and when I try to call my testMethod I get an runtime error: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I also tried to access the TableViewController with the viewControllers method of the NavigationController and then access the object at index 0. Same thing.
I'm very confused since in my Storyboard it shows its the custom class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I named my Storyboard MainStoryboard, which is also the default name for a Storyboard and so setting the storyboard in my project didn't seem to work. Made a new storyboard, named it differently, did everything else the same way and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you changed the subclass of the controller in the storyboard?

[image: Custom Table View Controller]

Notice how in the "Custom Class" box, I have put the name of the subclass that my TVC should be. Additionally, I created the storyboard element by dragging out a generic TVC and then setting the subclass.

Comment: Yes I have set the Table View Controller to my custom class in the storyboard.